# Having trouble getting list.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, listjs

So I am new to using JS and I have looked over the list.js site and can't seem to figure this out. I can't even get the demo to run on my server. I can get my code to work on web based places like Encode and what not, but not my server.

http://brewingbard.biz/smm/test/main-list2.html

Can someone please tell me why this is failing? I copy stuff that works in one place and put it up here and then it stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is running before the `<div id="users">` exists.
Therefore, it has nothing to operate on.

Move the invoking script block below the element.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="list.js" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Each `<script>` tag can only have *one* `src`.

You need to load each script in its own element.

Comment: please explain more on this.. it is not clear what you are reffering to

Comment: @patel.milanb the source code in the provided link (*in the OP*) contains a `script` tag with 3 `src` attributes..

Comment: I saw someone do that which is why I did that..it was the same when it was separate. But I'll put it back for arguments sake.

Comment: Yeah...that didn't change anything.

Comment: Either way, multiple src attributes is badly formed and unlikely to work even if your code did.